# How to clear boost function?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-function

Having a non-empty `boost::function`, how to make it empty (so when you call `.empty()` on it you'll get `true`)?

Answer (score 4):

Simply assign it `NULL` or a default constructed `boost::function` (which are empty by default):

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int foo(int) { return 42; }

int main()
{
    boost::function<int(int)> f = foo;
    std::cout << f.empty();

    f = NULL;
    std::cout << f.empty();

    f = boost::function<int(int)>();
    std::cout << f.empty();
}
```

Output: `011`

Answer (score 4):

f.clear() will do the trick. Using the example above

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int foo(int) { return 42; }

int main()
{
    boost::function<int(int)> f = foo;
    std::cout << f.empty();

    f.clear();
    std::cout << f.empty();

    f = boost::function<int(int)>();
    std::cout << f.empty();
}
```

will yield the same result.